# '/var/www/html/webservice/WMGetService.php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing one strange issue.

my php file path is like

```
/var/www/html/webservice/webservice/WMGetService.php
```

But while calling same name folder is merge to one and calling url like

```
/var/www/html/webservice/WMGetService.php
```

and it will giving error like

```
'/var/www/html/webservice/WMGetService.php' not found or unable to stat
```

My calling url is:

```
domainname/webservice/webservice/WMGetService.php
```

I dont get this why calling url change automatically.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information before a useful answer can be found; perhaps show some code from `WMGetService.php` where it's loading the next file. How are you trying to access this; usually PHP scripts are run through a webserver which would give an http:// location (like `http://localhost/webservice/webservice/WMGetService.php`) and you've posted file paths as if you're accessing `file:///var/www/html/webservice/webservice/WMGetService.php`; you'll need to run your code through the webserver directly for the PHP interpreter to work properly.